# wso2 ESB services

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am using ESB which is having Admin services on port 9443 and when we define proxy service it is exposed as /services but on port 8243, how to distingush them if I want load balancer in front of esb servers, do you have idea how to change /services separately or idea how to implement some logic which would allow me to have as frontend port 443 ?

I am not able to find configuration files where those would be separated ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change 9443 with 433 you need to go to: 
/repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml

And replace 9443 by 433 in this section:

```
<Connector  protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
            port="9443"
            bindOnInit="false"
            sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"
            maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
            acceptorThreadCount="2"
            maxThreads="250"
            minSpareThreads="50"
            disableUploadTimeout="false"
            enableLookups="false"
            connectionUploadTimeout="120000"
            maxKeepAliveRequests="200"
            acceptCount="200"
            server="WSO2 Carbon Server"
            clientAuth="false"
            compression="on"
            scheme="https"
            secure="true"
            SSLEnabled="true"
            keystoreFile="${carbon.home}/repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks"
            keystorePass="wso2carbon" 
            compressionMinSize="2048"
            noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata"
            compressableMimeType="text/html,text/javascript,application/x-javascript,application/javascript,application/xml,text/css,application/xslt+xml,text/xsl,image/gif,image/jpg,image/jpeg"
            URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

Also, if you want to replace the NIO ports you need to go to:
 /repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml
and change the HTTP Receiver(8280) and HTTPS Receiver(8243) ports